# Active Model Serializer caching of calculated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to to cache a collection of items, this is my AMS:

```
class ApplicationCategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  cache({})
  cache key: 'application_category', expires_in: 3.days

  attributes :id
  attributes :name
  attributes :active
  attributes :group
  attributes :num_of_protocols

  belongs_to :group do |serializer|
    serializer.attributes[:group][:name]
  end


  def num_of_protocols
    ApplicationCategory.find(object.id).protocol_categories.count
  end
end
```

My problem is that without the `:num_of_protocols` part it takes 10 times faster to generate the response,

when I look at the log I can see:

```
Started GET "/application_categories.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-04 19:12:27 +0300
Processing by ApplicationCategoriesController#index as JSON
  ApplicationCategory Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "application_categories".* FROM "application_categories"
[active_model_serializers]   Group Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2066]]
[active_model_serializers]   ApplicationCategory Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "application_categories".* FROM "application_categories" WHERE "application_categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]    (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "protocol_categories" INNER JOIN "application_categories_protocol_categories" ON "protocol_categories"."id" = "application_categories_protocol_categories"."protocol_category_id" WHERE "application_categories_protocol_categories"."application_category_id" = ?  [["application_category_id", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2066]]
[active_model_serializers]   ApplicationCategory Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "application_categories".* FROM "application_categories" WHERE "application_categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]    (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "protocol_categories" INNER JOIN "application_categories_protocol_categories" ON "protocol_categories"."id" = "application_categories_protocol_categories"."protocol_category_id" WHERE "application_categories_protocol_categories"."application_category_id" = ?  [["application_category_id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2066]]
...................... [many many more lines like those...]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "application_categories".* FROM "application_categories" WHERE "application_categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 608]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "protocol_categories" INNER JOIN "application_categories_protocol_categories" ON "protocol_categories"."id" = "application_categories_protocol_categories"."protocol_category_id" WHERE "application_categories_protocol_categories"."application_category_id" = ?  [["application_category_id", 608]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "application_categories".* FROM "application_categories" WHERE "application_categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 609]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "protocol_categories" INNER JOIN "application_categories_protocol_categories" ON "protocol_categories"."id" = "application_categories_protocol_categories"."protocol_category_id" WHERE "application_categories_protocol_categories"."application_category_id" = ?  [["application_category_id", 609]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "application_categories".* FROM "application_categories" WHERE "application_categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 610]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "protocol_categories" INNER JOIN "application_categories_protocol_categories" ON "protocol_categories"."id" = "application_categories_protocol_categories"."protocol_category_id" WHERE "application_categories_protocol_categories"."application_category_id" = ?  [["application_category_id", 610]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (1521.15ms)
```

how can I get better results with caching? - when I comment out the `cache` lines I get aprox. same times as with them, when I remove the `:num_of_protocols` I get same time with & without cache.

what am I configuring wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
def num_of_protocols
  object.protocol_categories.count
end
```

And, it's been a while for serializers for me, but I thought you were able to do this...

```
def num_of_protocols
  protocol_categories.count
end
```

And this is better ruby (in the case protocal_categories is already loaded as an array)

```
def num_of_protocols
  protocol_categories.size
end
```

And, if all that works or not, make sure you include protocol_categories and groups when you instantiate @application_category before you render to json.  You're doing too many queries.

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I write: def num_of_protocols
  object.protocol_categories.count
end I still get the multiple queries section. how can I avid this?

Comment: How can I configure a cache for the whole collection?